How to access HttpContextToken declared in a library?
I have an HttpInterceptor to show a progressbar when I'm making an http call.
intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
  if (request.context.get(SHOW_PROGRESSBAR)) {
    this.requestLoaderService.show();
    this.pendingRequestNumber++;

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      delay(0),
      finalize(() => {
        this.pendingRequestNumber--;

        if (this.pendingRequestNumber === 0) {
          this.requestLoaderService.hide();
        }
      }),
    );
  }
}

This HttpInterceptor is in an Angular library. I would like to set the value of an HttpContextToken (SHOW_PROGRESSBAR) in my Angular app.
this.http.request<KweResponse<any>>(
        method,
        this.url.getString(endpoint),
        {
          body,
          headers: options?.headers,
          params: options?.params,
          observe: 'response',
          context: new HttpContext()
            .set(SHOW_PROGRESSBAR, options?.withProgressbar ?? true)
        }
      )

How can I declare the HttpContextToken in my library for it to be accessible from my app?

To use the HttpContextToken in your Angular library and access it from your app, you can use these steps.

Provide the HttpContextToken
This is usually done by creating a new file (my_token.ts).
then declare the HttpContextToken there. This will allows the interceptor/ observable or consumer of your library to use the token.

Here is how to use it according to the docs ref

A token used to manipulate and access values stored in HttpContext.


class HttpContextToken<T> {
  constructor(defaultValue: () => T)
  defaultValue: () => T
}


Using the HttpContextToken in the Interceptor see ref:

I have modified your code which takes into account, how the interceptor would evaluate each token
@Injectable()
export class YourHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private pendingRequestNumber = 0;

  constructor(private requestLoaderService: RequestLoaderService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    if (request.context.get(SHOW_PROGRESSBAR)) {
      this.requestLoaderService.show();
      this.pendingRequestNumber++;

      return next.handle(request).pipe(
        next(() => {
          this.pendingRequestNumber--;
          if (this.pendingRequestNumber === 0) {
            this.requestLoaderService.hide();
          }
        }),
        error((err) => {
          if (this.err.message) {
             return err
          }
        }),
        complete(() =>{});
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}

In your Angular App
You can then do something like this in your app.
// App
import { HttpClient, HttpContext } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SHOW_PROGRESSBAR } from 'path/to/my_token.ts)'; // <- token

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

requestData(endpoint: string, options?: { withProgressbar?: boolean }) {
  return this.http.request<type>(
    'GET', /, 'POST' etc.
    endpoint,
    {
      context: new HttpContext().set(SHOW_PROGRESSBAR, options?.withProgressbar ?? true)
    }
  );
}

To access your token, you can simply create a service for the token

// where you app lives include inside this file-> my-token-provider.service.ts)
import { Injectable, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpContextToken } from '@angular/common/http';

// my token service provider
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MyTokenProviderService {
  getProgressbarToken(): HttpContextToken<boolean> {
    return new HttpContextToken<boolean>(() => true);
  }
}

Then you can use it anywhere like this in your nice app
@Injectable()
export class YourHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private requestLoaderService: RequestLoaderService,
    private mytokenProviderService: MyTokenProviderService // Inject token provider
  ) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<mytype>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<mytype>> {
    const SHOW_PROGRESSBAR = this. mytokenProviderService.getProgressbarToken();
}
// ... the rest of your nice code ...

}



Thanks for your detailed answer.
The Token would be defined in the App (the file my_token.ts has a local path) how would I access it in the interceptor from the library ?

Hi @R3N0 You can use dependency injection to provide the token. I would update my answer

Thanks ! I defined the constant SHOW_PROGRESSBAR in the MyTokenProviderService and everything works fine.

awesome, I am glad it works. always happy to help.
